# SSRS Report Viewer in MVC app (but web form) gives me the following error

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I'm getting the following error for a web form page in an MVC application.  I'm trying to set the parameters programmatically (so the report has an ID/year parameters and I set both with valid values), and I get the error:

The parameter '{0}' cannot be an empty string.
Parameter name: cookie.Domain

Any idea why I am getting this error and what I can do to address it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured out that part; I was passing in the text "Domain" if I passed in a null domain value (via the component that wraps the credentials).  I change this to use "" if the domain is null, and it works now...

Weird.